# how to add a grouping to the output of a function?

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that returns a set of data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a(n int)
    RETURNS TABLE
            (
                r int
            )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$function$
BEGIN
    for i in 1..n
        loop
            RETURN QUERY
                execute 'SELECT * FROM generate_series(1,10,2);'
            ;
        end loop;
end;
$function$;
```

Can you please tell me how to edit it so that the result is like

```
select  sum(j)
from (select a(10) as j) k
```

Generally, I want to understand how to write a subquery to the set of data received after the loop. Thanks!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a table so you can use that in a standard SQL command with `LIMIT 1 OFFSET (n * 0.75)` to get the 75th percentile row in the output:

```
SELECT *
FROM bootstrap_percentile(bootstrap_column, schema_name, tab_name, n)
LIMIT 1 OFFSET ((n * 0.75)::int)
```

This is the record **after** the 75th percentile unless `n` is a multiple of 4. Subtract 1 as required.